# Making a new directory with OS module

Tags: python, operating-system

How can I create a new directory with OS module, I know it is os.mkdir but what are the arguments to be passed?

Comment: If only that function had documentation online...  [Oh wait, it does.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
  
# Directory 
directory = "GeeksForGeeks"
  
# Parent Directory path 
parent_dir = "/home/User/Documents"
  
# Path 
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory) 
  
# Create the directory 
# 'GeeksForGeeks' in 
# '/home / User / Documents' 
os.mkdir(path) 
print("Directory '%s' created" %directory)
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-mkdir-method/